# How to click on a button and drop select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my select option html code

```
<select id="font">
        <option value="School">School</option>
        <option value="'Ubuntu Mono'">SansitaOne</option>
        <option value="Tangerine">Tangerine</option>
        <option value="Inconsolata">Inconsolata</option>
    </select>
    <button id="drop">Display</button>
```

And here is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $('#drop').click(function(event) {
            what to do here...
  });
    </script>
```

Any help would be appreciate!
Thank in advance

Comment: You mean open the drop-down?

Comment: @Line Tum : i am not getting your question exactly..?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe take a look at following : 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp

you should be able to do :

`$('#drop').click(function(event) {
            var x = document.getElementById("font").selectedIndex;
            var y = document.getElementById("font").options;
            alert("Index: " + y[x].index + " is " + y[x].text);
  });`

Comment: Thanks @Deniz Cileci. Now I have found the soloution!